# ssrs export to Excel slow performance

Tags: excel, reporting-services

I have a report which consist of several textboxes and a tablix with row grouping. I have another two tablixes inside that group(perhaps I should merge them, since they consume the same dataset? They were separated due to the designer's requirements). Each group has a page break and group name(a critical condition- Excel's sheets should be named). Those two tablixes consist of ~50 columns and two rows- one for headers and one for values. The largest possible dataset consist of 31 * 24 * 16 rows. All cells use an evaluation function for background color's value(it's not very complicated). And it takes ~15 seconds for SSRS to generate a preview for this report.

Using .NET LocalReport class this report is exported to the Excel. On my machine and on the development server it takes something about 20 seconds. On one of the client's machines it takes more than 15 minutes.

I've already removed all functions for aggregation. And there is only one merged column header in report. What else might help?

Comment: Since report processing is handled locally, performance depends on the pc hardware, especially if the report dataset has many rows, the report calculations are complicated, etc. Also if the dataset is large you may have network issues.  Try using tools like task manager or resource monitor on the pc during report execution to see what causes the bottleneck (cpu,ram, network). I would recommend to use a report server if you have complicate report's and not too powerfull pc

Answer (score 0):

The performance issue can be because the ssrs and the database not in in the same network segment.

When you run from your own machine, remember to refresh the report twice or thrice time with the refresh button because ssrs cache can hide performance issue.

Another cause is run a subreport per row. The subreport rendering is very slow.